# Weekly Countdown timer for church services

Tags: timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I am trying to build my church's website and I want to have a countdown timer for the 8:30 AM service and the 11 AM Service. I would life for the timer to countdown until 8:30 AM Sunday then display LIVE NOW for an hour then begin counting down until 11 AM Sunday and then display LIVE NOW for an hour then countdown until the next Sunday all over again.

I've found plenty of countdown timers but I haven't found any that were for reoccurring events each week. And none supported a some sort of display at zero.

Would any of you much smarter people than me be so kind as to help me out?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Here is a countdown timer widget for your site, Im sure you can edit it to your liking:

```
<div style="background:#000;width:350px; height:260px;font:0px sans-serif;text-    
align:left;"><object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" id="cdtw" 
width="350" height="240" style="outline:none"><param name="movie" 
value="http://countingdownto.com/c/w.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="eid=450004" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
<embed name="cdtw" src="http://countingdownto.com/c/w.swf" flashvars="eid=450004" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="350" height="240" allowscriptaccess="always" 
bgcolor="#000000" style="outline:none"></embed></object><br/> <a 
href="http://countingdownto.com" style="font:bold 8px Arial;padding-
left:19px;color:#444;">COUNTDOWN WIDGET</a></div>
```